# Как сделать авторизацию через Github на React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Логика:

1. Пишем в инпут любой логин который существует в github проверяем,  проверяем есть ли такой логин + делаем проверку password, если есть убираем с кнопки атрибут disabled, авторизируемся. Переходим на главную страницу.
2. Берем из полученного объекта под логином аватарку, отображаем его на главной странице после авторизации.

Покажите какой либо пример либо направьте на туториал.

Answer (score 2):

У вас не много не верное представление авторизации через OAuth2.0 протокол.

OAuth 2.0 - протокол авторизации, позволяющий выдать одному сервису (приложению) права на доступ к ресурсам пользователя на другом сервисе. Протокол избавляет от необходимости доверять приложению логин и пароль, а также позволяет выдавать ограниченный набор прав, а не все сразу.
подробнее [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/115163/).

Суть такова что вы в вашем приложении не узнаете пароль от Github, Google, .... пользователей вашего сайта, а получите лишь токен, как бы говоряший о том что это действительно тот кто авторизовался в GitHub. .... Что делать с ним решать вам вам лишь разрешается получить публичные данные Авторизованного guthub пользователя.

Comment: предполагаю, что автор хотел спросить о аутентификации (сделать страничку с запросом логина и пароля для получения токена)